# R markdown to use variables existing in the environment and not run code again

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Perhaps I am not using R markdown properly, but my first line of code load a very large data set and then does analysis. Every time I knit the pdf to see what it looks like, it runs all the code again, this takes quite a while. The data is already stored in the environment so is there a way of getting R to not run all the code again but display the pdf with the alterations made?

Comment: Use `cache=TRUE` in code chunks where you want to avoid re-computation.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I've done that for all r chunks, it's still extremely slow for some reason =/, also it seems to be reloading the packages each time even with the change

Comment: Separate the pkg loading into its own chunk (and don't cache `library` calls). If you have large data it still has to load them from cached rdata files. If you are willing to not use the knit command in rstudio then there are standalone knitt functions whim he will take into account the curent global environment but that is really not a good idea IMO.

Comment: @hrbrmstr why should i not cache library calls ?

Comment: [This is why you should not cache library calls](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/).

Comment: @hrbrmstr  It is not strictly true that you "should not cache library calls". The rule is: don't load packages via library() in a cached chunk if these packages will be used by uncached chunks. Per [Yihui Xie, author of knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/): "it is entirely OK to load packages in a cached chunk and use them only in cached chunks because knitr saves the list of packages for cached chunks, but uncached chunks are unable to know which packages are loaded in previous cached chunks."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case loading your very large data set is the problem, try special packages for reading your data like `readr`.

Alternative, since you working on the design or representation in you PDF, you can work on a subset of your data like only on the first 100000 rows.

Otherwise, I use the following code in my first code chunk

```
library(knitr)
# global setting to create this document
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE,
               echo=TRUE, # set to FALSE to remove the code output
               warning=FALSE, 
               message=FALSE)
```

so I don't need to set `cache=TRUE` in each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

My set of tricks is evolving:

1. a parameter to use on the chunk's `eval=params$do.readdata`
2. this type of construct:

```
    if (exists('<name of data table>') {
          load(<file>, verbose=TRUE) or st_read_feather...
       } else {
          <read in data>
       }
```

3. Until recently, i was using a cache option on the chunk, but recently learned that putting the import and processing of data in a function in order to remove it from the global environment (if memory is an issue) and return a smaller subset or result that is needed later.  So, caching may not be an option.